# How to sort 500-511 HTTP errors in a file produced daily on Grafana using Loki as Datasource

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

How to grep for only 500 errors (500-511) in a file that is created daily with date stamp in file name. These files are configured to be pushed by promtail agent to Loki server so I can visualize them on Grafana.  The files are being produced daily and this is an example of the file sss2022-03-16.txt.  I would like  to count and visualise this on grafana only the 500-511 HTTP errors for file produced each day.

On Grafana Loki I tried doing this `{job="cbas-dev-logs"} |= "500|501|502|503|504|505|506|507|508|509|510|511"` but that didn't grep specifically only the  500s HTTPs

Below you can see an example of the file sss2022-03-16.txt

10.32.10.181    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:04 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  500     73      N       0       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:06 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  501     73      N       0       h
10.32.42.249    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:27 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  500     73      N       1       h
10.32.10.181    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:34 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  302     73      N       0       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  503     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  502     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  502     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  504     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  511     73      N       1       h
10.32.26.124    ignore  19 Feb 2022 00:26:36 GMT        10.32.10.44     GET / HTTP/1.1  508     73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query selects not only HTTP statuses 5XX but all lines that contains 500-511 number. Try one of the solutions below:

**Solution-1:** try to use more specific query like this one :

```
{job="cbas-dev-logs"} |~ "HTTP/1.1 (500|501|502|503|504|505|506|507|508|509|510|511)"
```

Update: I have tried and it works for me.
Example for 500-511 codes:
[image]

**Solution-2:** use [patter parser](https://grafana.com/blog/2021/08/09/new-in-loki-2.3-logql-pattern-parser-makes-it-easier-to-extract-data-from-unstructured-logs/), so your query will look:

```
{job="cbas-dev-logs"} | pattern "<_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <_> <status> <_>" | status >= 500 and status <= 511
```

here is an example of the results:

Moreover, using pattern parser you can use `status` in the aggregation functions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but unfortunately this didn't help. I'm still stuck here trying to figure it out :(

Comment: @BenzeLawerence could you please explain why it does not work for you? I could help resolve the issue.

Comment: Yeah. I tried using the exact command you highlighted but it didn't grep the 500s HTTP error code so I thought that was because there was no 500s error at the moment so I decided to use the same command to grep for the 200s and 400s status code that was visible but still couldn't grep any of them. 
FYI, I can only grep one status code at a time but not multiple which is what I'm looking forward to.

Comment: @BenzeLawerence . i have checked and both solutions work for me. try solution #2